# native base customize components

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am following this link to customize my react-native components
[Theming NativeBase Apps](http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.4.6/customize)
but I am unable to find light.js and proceed further

Comment: are you saying that you didn't get it in /node_modules/native-base/Components/Themes/light.js

Comment: For latest native-base path is different. /node_modules/native-base/src/backward/Themes/light.js

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command after installing native-base in your root app directory.

```
node node_modules/native-base/ejectTheme.js
```

https://docs.nativebase.io/Customize.html#Customize

set version to 2.2.0 and it will show you the steps to theming nativeBase App.